Is the border crossing at Mae Sai/Tachileik closed to foreigners (i.e., who are citizens of neither Thailand nor Myanmar)?
I read on https://www.chiangmai-alacarte.com/blog/return-to-tachileik-in-myanmar/:

Update December, 2023: Currently, the border crossing at Mae Sai/Tachileik is closed to foreigners. We will keep you updated.

Has that border reopened yet for foreigners (i.e., who are citizens of neither Thailand nor Myanmar)?
https://www.go-myanmar.com/arriving-and-departing-over-land says it's open but they didn't deem useful to indicate any timestamp on their site, so I have no clue if their information is from yesterday or from 1990.

Given that Myanmar is effectively in a state of civil war right now, the situation may change very rapidly and I'd avoid travel even if the crossing is open.
